# Created new tag and started tagging, found existing tag, now what?

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-process, tag-wiki

Triggered by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37901677/can-i-get-the-new-bash-on-windows-10-to-load-profile) asking for a tag for [Bash running natively under Windows 10](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2016/03/30/run-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/), I tried finding such a tag, didn't find one, went ahead and created [windows-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash).

I suggested a short [wiki with excerpt](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/windows-bash/info) (edit currently pending) and started tagging suitable questions. A few questions in, I bumped into an existing tag, [ubuntu-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows), which covers exactly what my new tag aimed at covering.

I think that

- The tag name should contain "Bash" because I assume that's what people look for
- Tag wiki plus excerpt of [windows-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash) is better than the one of [ubuntu-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows), which has only excerpt that lacks usage guidance

so I'm somewhat reluctant to nuke the new tag. What are my options? What's the cleanest way forward?

- Make [ubuntu-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows) a synonym of [windows-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash) and abandoning the excerpt for the former, essentially merging it into the latter?
- Make [windows-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash) a synonym of [ubuntu-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows) and suggesting a tag wiki edit for the latter?
- Something else?

To give an idea of the scale, there are only a handful of questions tagged [windows-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash) and about two dozen tagged [ubuntu-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows).

---

**Update**

Turns out there is *another* tag for this already: [wsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl), as helpfully pointed out in [Vasily's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/326452/3266847). If I'm reading the discussion correctly, one way to go forward would be to make both [windows-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash) and [ubuntu-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows) synonyms of [wsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl) (and later potentially add a third, wordier synonym, like for example [win-subsystem-for-linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-subsystem-for-linux)), as it seems to be the most canonical of the bunch.

However, after [reading](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) [up](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) on synonyms and merging, I realized that creating the synonyms isn't quite possible currently: [wsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl) has just seven questions, and the top user has an answer score of four, so nobody can currently suggest synonyms or vote for them.

I guess we'll have to wait for a while until more questions are / can be tagged so synonymization can take place. I'll post a proper synonym request then. For now, I'll add some content to the currently empty wiki of [wsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl), as the other wikis will be lost when synonymizing, if I understand correctly.

Comment: Baah, the question itself is off topic. And if MS and Canonical did it right, bash on windows will behave the same way as bash in non-windows systems, like all portable programs should.

Comment: @Braiam Yes, the question is not stellar, but others are alright. I think Bash on Windows is special due to (non-)interaction with Windows applications, though... are you implying both tags are unneccessary?

Comment: In response to your update, it is not currently possible for a regular user to suggest or vote on synonyms. One of the [many and long-ignored problems with tag synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103211/can-we-allow-7-5k-users-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-without-a-score-of-5-in-the-tag). But a diamond moderator can do this now, with a single click.

Comment: @CodyGray So the point of posting an explicit merge/synonymize request on MSO is to see how the community feels about it so a diamond mod can then go ahead and do it?

Comment: Yes. Either because it takes an indefinite period of time for the community to do it on their own, or it is impossible for the community to do it on their own. Of course, this Meta-based approach is not perfect, either. Diamond mods don't exactly troll the [tag-synonyms] tag looking for work to do, and it's hard to ascertain exactly when community consensus has been reached. But you've got the general idea.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The proper name of the technology is [WSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsl/) (Windows Subsystem for Linux), and in fact we already have the [wsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl) tag which covers exactly same topic as [ubuntu-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows) and [windows-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash).

I think we should make both [ubuntu-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows) and [windows-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash) synonyms for [wsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl), with the following reasoning:

- [ubuntu-on-windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows) is an interim/informal term for [wsl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wsl), it was briefly used by Microsoft when the technology was first presented, but now it looks like Microsoft abandoned this name and settled with WSL
- The same goes for [windows-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash), but there's one more important point: the questions tagged [windows-bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash) mostly have nothing to do with the Bash shell itself, they ask how to run this or that Linux program on Windows

Comment: I completely agree with this answer, the only thing I'm a little iffy about is another TLA (three-letter acronym). The TWEs (tag wiki excerpts) certainly help to explain WTF WSL is, so I guess that's okay. But I wonder if the "master" tag (to which all others are synonymized) ought not be something more explicit, like `[win-subsystem-for-linux]`. (The max tag length is 25 chars, so this fits, and with auto-completion, no one will actually have to type it each time.)

Comment: @CodyGray I had the exactly same consideration, but the full name is so long it really doesn't make sense as a tag. And it looks like (somewhat surprisingly) "WSL" acronym doesn't have any other popular meaning which could be on-topic for SO.

Comment: VasilyAlexeev I think @CodyGray's point is that people who want to add this tag, (such as OP) will not find it if it's called `wsl` (such as OP). At least those users who attempt to tag properly should be able to easily do so.

Comment: @AndrasDeak true, but if we add the other two tags as synonyms it should solve this problem

Comment: That makes perfectly sense, so the desired final state of things would be [tag:wsl] as the "master tag", and [tag:ubuntu-on-windows] and [tag:windows-bash] as synonyms of it. (Maybe also a wordier version, such as [tag:win-subsystem-for-linux]?)

Comment: IMHO "win-subsystem-for-linux" makes much more sense than any short TLA. The 25 char tag limit is in place to keep tags short. No need to go beyond that. Sacrificing intelligibility in favor of lazy typing seems a bad idea.

Comment: If the question is about bash on windows, why won't tag with with 2 tags: `bash` and `windows`? `wsl` tag should be attached to the questions about the platform itself, not to the applications it's running.

Comment: @Haspemulator because, "tags should make sense as the only tag on the question". Is a question about bash on windows only a bash question, [I would say that yes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326440/created-new-tag-and-started-tagging-found-existing-tag-now-what?cb=1#comment358985_326440). Is a windows question... meh, windows has more moving parts that bash do (is an OS!) so using bash should be enough for most cases. Only stuff unique to the wsl environment use the other tag.